# Client SSL with an Intermediate Certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a self-signed root certificate and an intermediate certificated signed by that root. Basically something like this:

```
.
└── master (CA)
    └── servant1 (CA)
```

I have a few client certificates which are derived from  the `master->servant1` certificate chain:

```
.
└── master (CA)
    └── servant1 (CA)
        ├── client1
        ├── client2
        └── client3
```

I'm looking to authenticate these client certificates in nginx and I'm having a lot of trouble doing so.

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
upstream luci {
    server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen                  127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name             myserver;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                  127.0.0.1:443;
    server_name             myserver;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/myserver.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/myserver.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AES:!ECDH+3DES:!DH+3DES:!RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/servant1-ca-chain.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://luci;
    }
}
```

This should be pretty straightforward. All client certificates signed by the intermediate `servant1` CA should be allowed to connect to nginx.

However, when I attempt to access the server with these client certificates, I get this:

[image: a]

<sup>(obviously an incredibly detailed and helpful error)</sup>

I find this in my logs:

```
2013/12/01 22:46:18 [alert] 7478#0: *5 ignoring stale global SSL error (SSL: error:0407006A:lib(4):func(112):reason(106) error:04067072:lib(4):func(103):reason(114) error:0D0C5006:lib(13):func(197):reason(6)) while reading client request line, client: 192.168.1.208, server: myserver
```

Useful information here is:

> ignoring stale global SSL error

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had generated my certificates using OpenSSL and most probably screwed something up along the way.

My recommendation is to use [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) when at all possible for generating SSL certificates, as it's incredibly secure, feature-complete, and makes it easy to manage public and private keys, certificates, CSRs, and more.

Comment: perhaps you have solved this by now, though not the error you get is unrelated to the warning you extract from the log. Also you better stick to openssl rather than use a wrapping tool such as XCA - it is like learning with Rashi and Toysfes vs. Steinzalts...